# New Relic Synthetics configuring SSL

Tags: configuration, ssl-certificate, newrelic, synthetic

I am planning on using new relic to get alerts when my service is down. And when i read about it I got to know we can go it using new relic synthetics by adding a new monitor with the type of ping. Inorder to access my web services a SSL certificate needs to be configured.
 Does any one know how I can configure it? I couldn't find an option under the "Ping" configurations.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Configure Ping https website in NewRelic Synthetics :

1. [Create ping synthtic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Y2Z.jpg)
   Click on advanced option and check validate ssl if ssl handshake needed.
2. Select monitoring locations
3. Set the schedule
4. Provide email or existing alert policy to get notified